# Repeater ItemDataBound FindControl Reference is NULL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

In the code sample below e.Item.FindControl("btnSignup") isnot nothing, but btn is nothing.  Why is that?  How do I set the visibility of btnSignup in the footer of my repeater?

```
Protected Sub rptParticipants_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptParticipants.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then 

        Dim btn As New Button           
        btn = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnSignup"), Button)

        If btn IsNot Nothing Then
            btn.Visible = False
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: your code says "Singup" instead of "Signup" - does that match the markup?

Comment: Thanks @John.  That was a typo here not in my actual code.  I've edited my post to reflect this correction.

Answer (score 0):

What type is e.Item.FindControl("btnSignup") ?

I prefer coding it like this:

```
If Not (btn Is Nothing) Then
      '...
End If
```